# How to change Firefox's referer header for all http requests

Tags: firefox, security, http, privacy, http-referrer

When making a request for (for example) `http://example.com/foo/bar.baz`, Firefox sends a referer header indicating which page I clicked a link from, or is loading a picture, etc.  Eg:

```
Referer: http://somewhere.else.com/page.html
```

I would like it to send

```
Referer: http://example.com/
```

instead, ie, to just send the root page of the site it's requesting from.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firefox add-on [RefControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/refcontrol/) can do this.

It has an option to always replace the `Referer` with the host only (stripping of the URL path). So if the real `Referer` is `http://example.com/foo/bar.html`, it becomes `http://example.com/`.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for; thanks!

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

[network.http.sendRefererHeader](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.sendRefererHeader) is Firefox option to control Referer header.

There are also some extensions like refspoof or "No Referrer".

Comment: (Probably should have mentioned this in the question, but) I already know about `sendRefererHeader`, it keeps Firefox from sending any referer at all, whereas I want to send a fake one.  Will look into those extensions though.

Comment: If this is one-off you can use `modify headers` extension to set your own headers. Then your Referrer header will be always the same. But my understanding of question is that you want to change your referrer header dynamically per request. As far as I know there is no easy way to do this.

Comment: coder, yeah, thats about right, I guess I'll have to write my own extention for it when I have some free time.

Answer (score 0):

I found FireFox RefControl plugin very easy and effective way to do this. 
Steps:

1. Add the plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/refcontrol/
2. restart firefox
3. top right side choose RefControl options from refcontrol tool.
4. click Add Site button now add the site(host) and select custom and add your Request Header Referer url
5. click Ok and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, and **RefControl** addon mentioned in existing answers never works anymore with Firefox Quantum.

An alternative is [**Referer Control** addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/referercontrol/) that has a similar functionality.